# MEF and Importing a Constructor without knowing the imports beforehand

Tags: c#, mef

I have a two simple classes:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace MefTest
{        
    internal class Foo
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public Foo(IBar bar)
        {
        }
    }

    internal interface IBar
    {
        void DoStuff();
    }

    [Export(typeof(IBar))]
    internal class Bar : IBar
    {
        public void DoStuff()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create the Foo class without already knowing that it requires Bar as an import. I know I can do this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MefTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            //This requires I know the imports, is there a way to do it without that knowledge beforehand?
            var bar = container.GetExportedValue<IBar>();
            var foo = new Foo(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to call Foo without knowing it needs Bar, and letting MEF figure that out for me. Is this possible, or do I always need to know the imports ahead of time like the example above?

Fairly new to MEF so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to put an `[Export]` attribute on `Foo`. Then you could just get the `Foo` directly:

```
[Export]
internal class Foo { ... }

...

var foo = container.GetExportedValue<Foo>();
```

Comment: Works for what I was asking. In my instance I also need to mark each one with [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]. My problem is I'll have over 150 objects like this. So object lifecycle is very important. What is the best way to clean up when an instance is no longer needed?

Comment: @Kelly I'm pretty sure if you specify `NotShared`, it will be cleaned up like any other .NET object--after you've removed all references. If `Foo` happens to implement `IDisposable`, remember to call `Dispose` or put it inside a `using` block.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, but instead of bogging this question down I've started a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442341/mef-object-lifecycle