# MEF Object Lifecycle

Tags: c#, mef

I have a single class called Foo:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace MefTest
{
    [Export]
    internal class Foo 
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("created foo");
        }

        ~Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dead");
        }            
    }
}
```

It's created as such:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MefTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            //EDIT: my problem, this returns Lazy<Foo> not Foo. Since I didn't call foo1.Value it was never actually created
            var foo1 = container.GetExport<Foo>(); 

            container.ReleaseExport(foo1);

            foo1 = null;

            GC.Collect();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

But it never seems to get disposed. I tried adding an IDisposible interface to it without any luck.

How can I ensure this gets cleaned up correctly? I thought that ReleaseExport would do it but the destructor never gets called, so it never appears to be cleaned up.

I've read http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parts%20Lifetime but I can't seem to see the problem with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `Foo` is a shared export. If you want it disposed as is, you can implement `IDisposable` on it and then call `Dispose` on the container.

The other option is to mark Foo as non-shared which will result in ReleaseExport calling the Dispose method on it.

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
internal class Foo 
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("created foo");
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dead");
    }            
}
```

The above is explained pretty well in the "Scoped operations and early reclaim of resources" section of the link you provided. Just remember that if you don't supply a PartCreationPolicy attribute, the export is shared by default.

Comment: It worked. The main issue was the call to container.GetExport was returning a Lazy<Foo> and I didn't notice. (how I didn't notice that is beyond me.) So it was never created in the first place, since I never accessed the value. After that your suggestions above work brilliantly. Thanks!